# How do i prevent a two-way binding from changing my property after ive programatically set it

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a piece of code that makes a db trip and pulls a bunch of records. Im using this method as a `Get` as well as a `Refresh`.

When `itemToSelectAfterLoading` is `null`, we select the first item (Get/Fresh load)

When `itemToSelectAfterLoading` is NOT `null`, we reselect that item after doing a reload.

```
    private async Task LoadGroupsAsync(RTG_Lookup2_Group itemToSelectAfterLoading)
    {
        _ea.GetEvent<ShowActivityIndicatorEvent>().Publish("Loading Groups...");

        ListOfLookupGroups = await _repository.GetGroupsAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(ListOfLookupGroups));

        var id = itemToSelectAfterLoading?.Id;
        SelectedLookupGroup = id == null ? ListOfLookupGroups.FirstOrDefault() : ListOfLookupGroups.FirstOrDefault(f => f.Id == id);

        //RebuildAdBuilderAndWhatIfLists.Execute(null);
        _ea.GetEvent<HideActivityIndicatorEvent>().Publish();
    }
```

On the xaml side of things, `SelectedLookupGroup` is bound to the `SelectedItem` property of a combobox with a TwoWay binding and `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"`

```
        <telerik:RadComboBox x:Name="GroupList"
                                 Grid.Column="1"
                                 ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfLookupGroups}"
                                 SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedLookupGroup, Mode=OneWay}"
                                 DisplayMemberPath="Name"
                                 IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
                                 IsEditable="True"
                                 IsReadOnly="True"
                                 Margin="5"
                                 Padding="5" />
```

Everything works fine as expected when doing a fresh load, but im having issues with the reload where i set `SelectedLookupGroup`.

With a breakpoint on my `SelectedLookupGroup` setter, it gets hit twice while the method is ran once.

The first time the setter is hit, the right item is being passed and the second time, the first item of my collection is being passed.

On the first hit, my callstack shows the calling method and the setter.

[image]

On the second hit, i only see the setter, not whats calling it.

[image]

If I change this property to a `OneWay` binding, my refresh works as expected, but i lose UI interaction. So i think the UI is changing this property AFTER i set it with `SelectedLookupGroup = itemToSelectAfterLoading ?? ListOfLookupGroups.FirstOrDefault();` in my `LoadGroupsAsync` method

I figured i need to change the binding type when im doing the (re)load, but im not sure how to do that.

E: I removed all the async code (no more await/async) and everything works as expected. Not a good solution but its good enough for now...

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you had set `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"`.

> Prior to **Q2 2010** version, the current item was synchronized with the
>   selected item. As a result, the first row of the GridView was selected
>   initially. To prevent this, you would simply need to set the
>   `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem` property of **RadGridView** to `False`. In Q2
>   2010 version, the IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem is **null** by default. In
>   this case, `SelectedItem` is synchronized with the `CurrentItem` only if
>   **CollectionView** is used as **ItemsSource**.

Ref. https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/controls/radgridview/selection/selecteditem-currentitem

Comment: passing `{x:null}` or `false` results in the same effect, except the second setter is passing `null` rather than the first object in my list. Same as omitting `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem`. So it seems my property is being `set` twice no matter what.

Comment: If so, you might need to check the `itemToSelectAfterLoading` value. I strongly believe it should be `null`.
Also, your `itemToSelectAfterLoading` argument will not work as expected. You need to pick the matching item from the newly set `ListOfLookupGroups` property and set that to `SelectedLookupGroup` property.

Comment: First hit, `itemToSelectAfterLoading` is not null (it selects the right item). Second hit is null, the method doesnt get called at that point. Also i noticed that typo as well, updated my code

Comment: clarify my previous comment:  `Refresh method` > `Set SelectedLookupGroup (correctly)` > `Set SelectedLookupGroup (incorrectly)`. `itemToSelectAfterLoading ` is the correct item whenever the method is called.